# SWT is build on top of Native interface , but why rendering is not slow

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am very new to SWT and while learning about it I came to know that all SWT components are native based while most Swing components are rendered in Java code and are considered light weight.

So these are my questions:

- Are SWT components heavy weight?
- Although SWT components are native based, how it is maintaining the thinnest possible user-interface API?

Comment: What do you mean by "thinnest layout"?

Comment: SOrry I mean , thinnest possible USER-INTERFACE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they are heavyweight in this sense. But this distinction isn't about performance at all and isn't really a good choice of words (IMHO).
2. It's precisely because they are based on native controls: rendering is done in C (or maybe C++), can be a lot more optimized for the specific platform, etc.

Comment: Agreed. "Heavy weight" and "light weight" are fairly common Swing terms, but they are often misunderstood.   You might expect that "light weight" components might perform better than "heavy weight" components, based on their names.  In fact "light" vs "heavy" in this context isn't a very good predictor of performance.